# Sending GPS coordinates to server by using JSON

Tags: android, json, gps, latitude-longitude

hello I want to send my gps coordinates and device id to the server. I am working on my server but just wanted to know if the code below is enough to post the coordinates..?

```
//get device id as following
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();



            //this is JSON part to put your information inside it
            String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"deviceid\":\""+deviceid+"\"}}";


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Post method to send data to server
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost();


            post.setURI(new URI("http://myserver.com/myphppage.php"));

            // set your post data inside post method    
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));

            // execute post request here 
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it out.

Basically it depends on the schema with which you access the server (`http` or `https`), but if the connection is not secured, that's pretty much it.

Comment: will access the server by http